# Download Photo not saved on local folder Xamarin Forms iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Saved image not showing on galary iOS(working fine on Android but not iOS)
 Here is my code for saving image to device

```
public void SavePicture(string name, byte[] data, string location = "Downloads")
        {
            var documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            documentsPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, location);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(documentsPath);

            string filePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, name);
            File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, data); // writes to local storage
}
```

Also allow for photo permission on info.plist
Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description

after execute this code I cant find the saved photo on iOS device
How to solve this?

Comment: saving an image to LocalStorage is NOT the same as saving it to the photo gallery.  Which one do you want to do?

Comment: Actually I want to download all documents to local folder which I specified.

Comment: The code you have should do that.  Is there a problem with it?  Are you getting an error or exception?

Comment: I am not gettng any exception,this code executed but when I an searching for download file I cant find that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in iOS to show an image into the gallery you have to write additional code as just using `File.WriteAllBytes` won't call the native `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` API to show it in the album.

To do that you will have to call this API as follows:

Make a dependency service:

```
  public interface ISavePhotosToAlbum
 {
    void SavePhotosWithFilePath(String Path);
 }
```

Now Add a native class and do the following:

```
 [assembly: Dependency(typeof(SaveToAlbum))]
 namespace SavePhotosDemo.iOS
{
      public class SaveToAlbum : ISavePhotosToAlbum
   {
       public void SavePhotosWithFilePath(String Path)
     {
            using (var url = new NSUrl (Path))
            using (var data = NSData.FromUrl (url))
            var image = UIImage.LoadFromData (data);          
            image.SaveToPhotosAlbum((img, error) =>
            {
                   if (error == null)
                   {//Success }                  
                   else
                   {//Failure}
            });
      }
   }
 }
```

Then use this Dependency Service as follows:

```
DependencyService.Get<ISavePhotosToAlbum>().SavePhotosWithStream(imageUrl);
```

Also, see to it that you add this dependency service call only for ios by adding it in an OnPlatform if statement.

### UPDATE

Use the following code to Add a Custom Photo Album in Photos library:

```
       void AddAssetToAlbum(UIImage image, PHAssetCollection album, string imageName)
        {
            try
            {
                PHPhotoLibrary.SharedPhotoLibrary.PerformChanges(() =>
                {
                    // Create asset request
                    var creationRequest = PHAssetCreationRequest.CreationRequestForAsset();
                    var options = new PHAssetResourceCreationOptions
                    {
                        OriginalFilename = imageName
                    };
                    creationRequest.AddResource(PHAssetResourceType.Photo, image.AsJPEG(), options);
                    // Change asset request (change album by adding photo to it)
                    var addAssetRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.ChangeRequest(album);
                        addAssetRequest.AddAssets(new PHObject[] { creationRequest.PlaceholderForCreatedAsset });
                }, (success, error) =>
             {
                    if (!success)
                        Console.WriteLine("Error adding asset to album");
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string h = ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

See to it that you request authorization using the `PHPhotoLibrary.RequestAuthorization` method as we need to request access to be able to use the Photos library. Also, **As of iOS 10** and above we also need to add an entry for access in the target .plist file for "Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description":

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Access to photos is needed to provide app features</string>
```

### Update

At the end, adding the following started showing the documents in the files app:

```
 <key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key> <true/> <key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key> <true/>
```

Comment: I already used this NSData,and its working fine but can you tell me how to save document on a folder in Xamarin iOS ?

Comment: Which specific folder are you trying to save this to?

Comment: I want to create a folder like "MyDownloads" and save this file here.so how to do this?

Comment: In my aplication I am showing the list of documents,and when user click any item then convert the item to Byte array and save it to local folder.My code executed but documents which I saved thats was not found on my local folders.

Comment: That is because you are saving it only in your document directory!

Comment: So where should I save?

Comment: First confirm one thing you want your pdf to be visible in the native `Files` app?

Comment: Yes it should be visible on file app so that user can open that file.

Comment: I found that solution for saving files on local folder,but I code executed but not showing on local. So please can you give me proper way to save this file and it should be visible on local directory.

Comment: I have a solution but it only works on iOS 11 and above, If interested check this https://www.appcoda.com/files-app-integration/ in this look for `Exposing Your App’s File to the Files App`

Comment: after adding this key:
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
    <true/>
    <key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
    <true/>
its working fine,and I can see the files

Comment: I will add this in the answer and you can mark this as right?